# The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type `System.Collections.Generic.List1[Web.ViewModel.HomePageView]`, but this dictionary requires a model item of type `Web.ViewModel.HomePageView`.

**HomePageView**

```
public class HomePageView
{
    public List<Category> Category { get; set; }
    public List<Slider> Slider { get; set; }
    public List<SliderImage> SliderImage { get; set; }
    public List<Contact> Contact { get; set; }
    public List<Setting> Setting { get; set; }

}
```

**HomeController**

```
namespace Web.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        private readonly ISliderRepository _sliderRepository;
        private readonly ISliderImageRepository _sliderImageRepository;
        private readonly ICategoryRepository _categoryRepository;
        private readonly IContactRepository _contactRepository;
        private readonly ISettingRepository _settingRepository;

        public HomeController(ISliderRepository sliderRepository, ISliderImageRepository sliderImageRepository, ICategoryRepository categoryRepository, IContactRepository contactRepository, ISettingRepository settingRepository)
        {
            _sliderRepository = sliderRepository;
            _sliderImageRepository = sliderImageRepository;
            _categoryRepository = categoryRepository;
            _contactRepository = contactRepository;
            _settingRepository = settingRepository;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var slider = _sliderRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            var sliderImg = _sliderImageRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            var category = _categoryRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            var contact = _contactRepository.GetAll().ToList();
            var setting = _settingRepository.GetAll().ToList();

            var Model = new HomePageView
            {
                Slider = slider,
                SliderImage = sliderImg,
                Category = category,
                Contact = contact,
                Setting = setting
            };

            List<HomePageView> newList = new List<HomePageView>();
            newList.Add(Model);

            return View(newList);
        }
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model Web.ViewModel.HomePageView
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "başlık ";
}
@Html.Partial("Slider", Model.Slider)
```

**Slider.cshtml**

```
@using Web.Helpers
@model System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.ViewModel.HomePageView>

@foreach (var db in Model.SelectMany(x => x.Slider))
{
    if (Model.SelectMany(x => x.Slider).Any())
    {
        <div class="carousel-inner">

            <div class="carousel-item active">

                @{
                    var sliderFirstImage = db.SliderImages.FirstOrDefault();
                    if (sliderFirstImage != null)
                    {
                        <img src="@Html.Base64SliderImage(sliderFirstImage)" srcset="@Html.Base64SliderImage(sliderFirstImage) 1920w, @Html.Base64SliderImage(sliderFirstImage) 425w" sizes="100vw" alt="">
                    }
                }

                <!--<img src="images/slider2.jpg" srcset="~/Content/images/slider2.jpg 1920w, ~/Content/images/slider2-425x146.jpg 425w" sizes="100vw" alt="The Best Construction WordPress Theme">-->
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="jumbotron-content">
                        <h1 class="jumbotron-content__title">@db.SliderTitle</h1>
                        <div class="jumbotron-content__description">
                            <p>
                                @db.SliderSubTitle
                            </p>
                            <p>
                                <a class="btn btn-primary" href="@db.Link1" target="_self">DAHA FAZLA</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-tertiary" href="@db.Link2" target="_self">İLETİŞİME GEÇ</a>
                            </p>
                        </div><!-- /.jumbotron-content__description -->
                    </div><!-- /.jumbotron-content -->
                </div><!-- /.container -->
            </div><!-- /.carousel-item -->

        </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
    }

}
```

Comment: I do not get your problem here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two things that I see going wrong:

First, you pass a `List<HomePageView>` to Index.cshtml, which expects a single `HomePageView` instance.

You are also passing a `List<Slider>` to the partial via `@Html.Partial("Slider", Model.Slider)`, but it expects a `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Web.ViewModel.HomePageView>` (as you defined in the top of the file at the `@model` definition).

Once you synchronise what you're sending to the views and what they expect, you should get less errors. It is probably better to just pass the model to the index, and then pass the slider collection on, if you're trying to do what I think you are. Try to keep clean models between Controllers and Views, it makes life easier when you start dealing with posts.